# add upload file button into datatables button

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

so i want to just make one button that act as file browser or file input and after i selecting file it will submit those file into form. and i tried to created it will only javascript including creating button since this button is extension from datatables.

so far i already can make the button act as file input but can't make it submit onchange... even thought i already put entire table inside form tag...

any idea how to do it?

note: i am using jquery datatables to create the button... here is some reference to what it is 
[datatables button extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/)

```
new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table,{
    buttons: [
        {
            text: '<i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Import File',
            action: function(){
                var fileSelector = $('<input type="file" name="import_file" onchange="this.form.submit();">');
                fileSelector.click();
                return false;
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**update**

here is my html stucture... i am using laravel so the form is generated with blade templating... but it is still a normal form but with a little token for security purpose...

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('admins.'.$kelas.'.importexcel'),'files' => true)) }}
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        // table heading
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        // table content
    </tbody>
</table>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This states the input is the form. You need to target the parent element. If there is not a parent aside from the form, change your onchange event from:

```
 onchange="this.form.submit();"
```

to:

```
 onchange="this.parentNode.form.submit();"
```

Currently your saying that the file input is the form

Comment: can you paste how your html looks in reference with the form.

Comment: you need to go up the dom to target the form

Comment: how about rather messing with dom can i just add form action into the javascript it self? is it possible for javascript to do that?

Comment: where's the input in reference with the html posted above, you have everything right, the only issue is your submit() isn't pointing at the form.

Comment: hmm i am using datatables... so i created button that associated with datatables button plugin for a better user interface...

Comment: in other words where is the input at inside the table, tbody, thead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118490/discussion-between-kaveelite-and-laurensius-tony).

Comment: i am not sure where the input file but if you ask the button position then it will be just before <table>